# How do I convert this Python punctuation-stripping function to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python

Please can anyone translate this python code into javascript.

```
#
def strip_punctuation(s):
#
    for c in ',.":;!%$':
#
        while s.find(c) is not -1:
#
            s.replace(c, '')
```

Comment: By the way your script does nothing. The result of s.replace is discarded. s is unchanged at the end. And strip_punctuation() returns None.

Comment: Hum. Good point. I guess my brain just kind of filled in the blanks.

Comment: point is to strip punctuation from the string. Now i need to remove symbols and numbers from the string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
function strip_punctuation(s) {
    return s.replace(/[,.":;!%$]/g, "");
}
```

Comment: thanks. can u please tell me how to strip symbols and number from the string. I cant find regular expression for that

Comment: @Ayaz: Then, instead of looking for one, how about learning to write them yourself at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ ?